# Access SQL Query - change FROM table in multiple queries from input

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have a series of almost identical queries which I have built in SQL View in Access as follows (the criteria changes in each different query)

```
SELECT t.SUBSECTION_VALUES, t.SECTION_CODE, t.SECTION_TYPE_NAME, t.CROSS_SECTIONAL_POSITION, t.START_METRES, t.END_METRES, t.RUT_RAW, t.[3M], t.[10M], t.CRACKING, t.LHS_TEXTURE, t.UKPMS_RCI_RURAL_OR_URBAN_UID, t.UKPMS_RCI_DOT_CLASSIFICATION_UID
FROM [Renfrewshire Raw Data] AS t
WHERE (((t.UKPMS_RCI_RURAL_OR_URBAN_UID)=1) AND ((t.UKPMS_RCI_DOT_CLASSIFICATION_UID)=4))
ORDER BY t.SUBSECTION_VALUES DESC;
```

I am looking for a way to change  the `FROM [tablename]` bit in all of the queries at once, maybe from some kind of input box?

I hope this is possible!

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you're happy to use VBA, you could use the following subroutine:

```
Public Sub ChangeTable(strQueryName As String, strNewTable As String)

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim sqlString As String

    Set db = CurrentDb() 'Sets the database'
    Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("" & strQueryName & "") 'Tells the sub which query to look at'

    sqlString = Replace(qdf.SQL, "[Renfrewshire Raw Data]", "" & strNewTable & "", 1) 'Grabs the sql from your query and replaces the table name'
    qdf.SQL = sqlString 'Puts your new sql back into the query'

End Sub
```

This will grab the sql from your query and replace the table name with your new table name. You can create a form if you want and grab the two variables needed by the sub from there.